# Possible MAX combination based on condinatio in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get the possible combination of data based on condition. I tried the same thing with Row_NUmber and stuff function but it is working for some combination only. not for all.

Here is the data:

[image]
[image]

Here is the required Output:

[image]

Explanation of Output:

As you can see in the first image Id 1 and Id2 has same data but different LinkId for some of the ID1 and ID2 combination. But I need only data with LInkId 1.

If you see the output 1. So, in ID1 297010 has 5 different ID2. So, 1st number is 297010. for ID2 we have 306362. So, we need to go in ID1 column for 306362 and need to check the linkid for ID2 column for 297010. So, LinkId is 1 so it will be added to Combination. So, Now our Combination is 297010, 306362. Now let's check for 303419 for ID1 = 297010. We need to go to ID1 = 303419 and need to check ID2 = 297010 and 306362 which has LinkId 1 and now we also need to check ID1 =306362, 297010 for ID2 = 303419 where linkid = 1. So, both of the condition is satisfying. So, 303419 can be included in combination. So, now our combination is 297010, 306362, 303419. Now next number in ID2 is 304605 which has Linkid = 2. So, it will not be included in combination. Next number in ID2 is 304875. Now we need to got to ID1 = 304875 and need to check ID2 = 297010, 306362, 303419 and we can see that for ID1 = 304875 and ID2 = 306362 has LinkId = 2 so, It will also not be included in combination. Next number is 306311. Now we need to got to ID1 = 306311 and need to check for ID2 = 297010, 306362, 303419 and need to check for LinkId. we can see that all LinkId = 1. so, it will be included in combination. So, our first output is 297010, 306362, 303419, 306311. Which is second output in image for output.

I am trying this from last one week but I am not able to get any clue.
If anyone can help me with this one then it would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Since there are six distinct values of `ID1`, does that you mean you want six entries in the output?

Comment: Nope, there are six distict value of ID1. But when we are trying to make combination then it will turn into same combinations. so, I don't need those same combinations. Order of number doesn't matter. When I was checking manually this things it is giving me 3 combination which is shown on output.

Comment: So in case two or more of the six combinations we come up with are same, you want to de-dup them. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't provide data as images, provide data as text.

Comment: What is condinatio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working:

**Raw Version For Your Example**

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID1 ID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID1) SEED
        , 1 I
        , CAST(1 AS bigint) R
        , CAST(NULL AS bigint) R_PREV
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE LINKID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        ID2
        , SEED
        , I
        , R
        , R_PREV
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                T.ID2
                , C.SEED
                , C.I + 1 I
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.ID2) R
                , C.R R_PREV
            FROM
                cte C
                JOIN YourTable T ON C.ID = T.ID1
            WHERE
                T.LINKID = 1
                AND T.ID2 > C.ID
        ) Q
)
,

cte2
AS
(
    SELECT
        CombinationID
        , Combination
        , ID
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CombinationID) C
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                C1ID
                , C2ID
                , C3ID
                , C4ID
                , C5ID
                ,
                    CAST(C1ID AS varchar) +
                    ISNULL(', ' + CAST(C2ID AS varchar), '') +
                    ISNULL(', ' + CAST(C3ID AS varchar), '') +
                    ISNULL(', ' + CAST(C4ID AS varchar), '') +
                    ISNULL(', ' + CAST(C5ID AS varchar), '') Combination
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1ID, C2ID, C3ID, C4ID, C5ID) CombinationID
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        C1.ID C1ID
                        , C2.ID C2ID
                        , C3.ID C3ID
                        , C4.ID C4ID
                        , C5.ID C5ID
                    FROM
                        cte C1
                        LEFT JOIN cte C2 ON
                            C1.SEED = C2.SEED
                            AND C1.I + 1 = C2.I
                            AND C1.R = C2.R_PREV
                            AND C1.ID < C2.ID
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C1.ID AND ID2 = C2.ID) = 1
                        LEFT JOIN cte C3 ON
                            C2.SEED = C3.SEED
                            AND C2.I + 1 = C3.I
                            AND C2.R = C3.R_PREV
                            AND C2.ID < C3.ID
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C1.ID AND ID2 = C3.ID) = 1
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C2.ID AND ID2 = C3.ID) = 1
                        LEFT JOIN cte C4 ON
                            C3.SEED = C4.SEED
                            AND C3.I + 1 = C4.I
                            AND C3.R = C4.R_PREV
                            AND C3.ID < C4.ID
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C1.ID AND ID2 = C4.ID) = 1
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C2.ID AND ID2 = C4.ID) = 1
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C3.ID AND ID2 = C4.ID) = 1
                        LEFT JOIN cte C5 ON
                            C4.SEED = C5.SEED
                            AND C4.I + 1 = C5.I
                            AND C4.R = C5.R_PREV
                            AND C4.ID < C5.ID
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C1.ID AND ID2 = C5.ID) = 1
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C2.ID AND ID2 = C5.ID) = 1
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C3.ID AND ID2 = C5.ID) = 1
                            AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C4.ID AND ID2 = C5.ID) = 1
                    WHERE C1.I = 1
                ) Q
        ) Q
        UNPIVOT
        (
            ID FOR IDs IN (C1ID, C2ID, C3ID, C4ID, C5ID)
        ) U
)

SELECT Combination
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CombinationID
            , Combination
            , C
            , CombinationIDCheck
            , CountCheck
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CombinationID ORDER BY CountCheck DESC) R
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    C1.CombinationID
                    , C1.Combination
                    , C1.C
                    , C2.CombinationID CombinationIDCheck
                    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C1.CombinationID, C2.CombinationID) CountCheck
                FROM
                    cte2 C1
                    LEFT JOIN cte2 C2 ON
                        C1.ID = C2.ID
                        AND C2.C > C1.C
            ) Q
    ) Q
WHERE
    R = 1
    AND
        (
            CombinationIDCheck IS NULL
            OR CountCheck < C
        )
```

**Dynamic SQL Version**

```
DECLARE @MaxIteration int
;

WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID1 ID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID1) SEED
        , 1 I
        , CAST(1 AS bigint) R
        , CAST(NULL AS bigint) R_PREV
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE LINKID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        ID2
        , SEED
        , I
        , R
        , R_PREV
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                T.ID2
                , C.SEED
                , C.I + 1 I
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.ID2) R
                , C.R R_PREV
            FROM
                cte C
                JOIN YourTable T ON C.ID = T.ID1
            WHERE
                T.LINKID = 1
                AND T.ID2 > C.ID
        ) Q
)

SELECT @MaxIteration = MAX(I)
FROM cte

-- Build variables for cte2

DECLARE
    @OuterSelectFields varchar(255) = ''
    , @OuterSelectCombination varchar(255) = ''
    , @InnerSelectFields varchar(255) = ''
    , @LeftJoins varchar(8000) = ''

DECLARE @n int = 1

WHILE @n <= @MaxIteration
BEGIN

    IF @n = 1

        BEGIN

            SET @OuterSelectFields = @OuterSelectFields + 'C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + 'ID'
            SET @OuterSelectCombination = @OuterSelectCombination + 'CAST(C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + 'ID AS varchar)'
            SET @InnerSelectFields = @InnerSelectFields + 'C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.ID C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + 'ID'

        END

    ELSE

        BEGIN

            SET @OuterSelectFields = @OuterSelectFields + ', C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + 'ID'
            SET @OuterSelectCombination = @OuterSelectCombination + ' + ISNULL('', '' + CAST(C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + 'ID AS varchar), '''')'
            SET @InnerSelectFields = @InnerSelectFields + ', C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.ID C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + 'ID'

            DECLARE @CheckLinkIDClauses varchar(1000) = ''

            DECLARE @n2 int = 1

            WHILE @n2 <= @n - 1
            BEGIN

                SET @CheckLinkIDClauses = @CheckLinkIDClauses + ' AND (SELECT LINKID FROM YourTable WHERE ID1 = C' + CAST(@n2 AS varchar) + '.ID AND ID2 = C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.ID) = 1'

                SET @n2 = @n2 + 1

            END

            SET @LeftJoins = @LeftJoins + ' LEFT JOIN cte C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + ' ON C' + CAST(@n - 1 AS varchar) + '.SEED = C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.SEED AND C' + CAST(@n - 1 AS varchar) + '.I + 1 = C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.I AND C' + CAST(@n - 1 AS varchar) + '.R = C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.R_PREV AND C' + CAST(@n - 1 AS varchar) + '.ID < C' + CAST(@n AS varchar) + '.ID' + @CheckLinkIDClauses

        END

    ;

    SET @n = @n + 1

END

-- Build SQL statement

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) =
    '
        WITH cte
        AS
        (
            SELECT
                ID1 ID
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID1) SEED
                , 1 I
                , CAST(1 AS bigint) R
                , CAST(NULL AS bigint) R_PREV
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE LINKID = 1

            UNION ALL

            SELECT 
                ID2
                , SEED
                , I
                , R
                , R_PREV
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        T.ID2
                        , C.SEED
                        , C.I + 1 I
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.ID2) R
                        , C.R R_PREV
                    FROM
                        cte C
                        JOIN YourTable T ON C.ID = T.ID1
                    WHERE
                        T.LINKID = 1
                        AND T.ID2 > C.ID
                ) Q
        )
        ,

        cte2
        AS
        (
            SELECT
                CombinationID
                , Combination
                , ID
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CombinationID) C
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT ' + @OuterSelectFields + '
                        , ' + @OuterSelectCombination + ' Combination
                        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @OuterSelectFields + ') CombinationID
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT DISTINCT ' + @InnerSelectFields + '
                            FROM
                                cte C1' + @LeftJoins + '
                            WHERE C1.I = 1
                        ) Q
                ) Q
                UNPIVOT
                (
                    ID FOR IDs IN (' + @OuterSelectFields + ')
                ) U
        )

        SELECT Combination
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    CombinationID
                    , Combination
                    , C
                    , CombinationIDCheck
                    , CountCheck
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CombinationID ORDER BY CountCheck DESC) R
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            C1.CombinationID
                            , C1.Combination
                            , C1.C
                            , C2.CombinationID CombinationIDCheck
                            , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C1.CombinationID, C2.CombinationID) CountCheck
                        FROM
                            cte2 C1
                            LEFT JOIN cte2 C2 ON
                                C1.ID = C2.ID
                                AND C2.C > C1.C
                    ) Q
            ) Q
        WHERE
            R = 1
            AND
                (
                    CombinationIDCheck IS NULL
                    OR CountCheck < C
                )
    '

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Mack. It is giving the combinations. But if you take look at first combination: 297010, 303419, 304875, 306311, 306362. So, when we are looking at ID1 = 297010 and look at 303419 in ID2 then it has LinkID as 1. so, now we have to look vice versa for both the ID1 and  ID2. for ID1 = 303419 and ID2 = 297010 then we have LinkId =1. So, we can consider 303419 in combination. Now the next value is 304875. so, for ID1 = 297010 we need to check both 304875 and 303419 in ID2 and we will find 1 in LinkId.

Comment: Now we need to go in ID1 = 304875 and need to check for 297010 and  303419 and need to find 1.same way we need to go to ID1 = 303419 and need to check 297010 and 304875 in ID2. and we have 1 in LinkID. So, now we can consider 304875. Now if you look at ID1 = 303362 then you won't be find linkid = 1 for ID2= 304875. so, 303362 won't be comes in combination.

Comment: you can see that in the output number 7 which is 297010, 306362 already included in above output. So, it won't be consider as combinations.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it makes sense now. I've posted a working solution!